# Why does text in paragraph overlap and not create a new line?

Tags: html, paragraph

I have a division set up with a heading and paragraph. When I load the page, the text overlaps as if it's run to the bottom of the div and has nowhere to go. My assumption was that the div would expand vertically as text was added to it, but it doesn't (not in my case, at least). Important to know that I changed the font from a smaller (Times New Roman) to larger (Georgia). After this change the text problem happened. Thank you.

```
<div id="fall">
  <h3> Exile L'Empereur </h3>
  <br>
  <p>  Napoleon was exiled to Elba. After Waterloo he was exiled to St. Helena. </p>
  <p>  Napoleon was exiled to Elba. After Waterloo he was exiled to St. Helena. </p>
  <p>  Napoleon was exiled to Elba. After Waterloo he was exiled to St. Helena. </p>
```

==============

```
 #fall {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 5px;
  background-image: url(../images/fleurdelis.png);
  background-position: top right;   
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #CBEDF2;
  background-size: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 0px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  border: 2px solid black;
 }
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do what you say that it does http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/16updjny/

Comment: You can add: font-family: "Georgia"

Comment: @j08691 code will exhibit the problem when you change the width of the div - like here: http://jsfiddle.net/16updjny/1/

Comment: You need to understand how line height works. If you have paragraph - line height will be the total height, including the font when your text will start wrapping at the end of the line. 
If you have separate paragraphs they will have normal margins around them and line height will not affect that that much.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the `line-height` to small. I'm assuming you thought it is the height between two lines of text, but it's not. Check the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: It looks fine if you just delete the line-height part.

Answer (score 0):

set the alignment of paragraph.
increase the margin of the text.

To find more about paragraph visit the link.

http://entertainment7899.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-create-paragraph-with-html.html